# Can't figure on why .hover is working but .on mouse enter is not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

I am trying to have it so that you can hover over dynamically added content. I found code that allows a scroll-able menu drop-downs but only for .hover() and but I want to dynamically add these menu drop-downs. I found information regarding on click mouseenter and mouseleave but this doesn't seem to work the way I did it. Both are posting of the code.

I essentially want to have the functionality of the first code but have it do this to dynamically added elements, since .hover is bound from page creation, I cannot do this easily and have not found a working solution yet. I have no idea why the second solution doesn't work like the hover. If any can could they please explain that to me that would be great because everything I read said it should work. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

THE FIRST LINE OF EACH PIECE OF CODE IS THE ONLY DIFFERENCE BETWEEN THESE TWO PIECES OF CODE. BUT I DON"T KNOW WHETHER IT COULD BE THE WAY I AM CALLING MY OBJECT THAT IS CAUSING THE PROBLEM SO I ADDED BOTH

Working Code

```
 $(".dropdown > li").hover(function() {

         var $container = $(this),
             $list = $container.find("ul"),
             $anchor = $container.find("a"),
             height = $list.height() * 1.1,       // make sure there is enough room at the bottom
             multiplier = height / maxHeight;     // needs to move faster if list is taller
        //alert("Hi");
        // need to save height here so it can revert on mouseout            
        $container.data("origHeight", $container.height());

        // so it can retain it's rollover color all the while the dropdown is open
        $anchor.addClass("hover");

        // make sure dropdown appears directly below parent list item    
        $list
            .show()
            .css({
                paddingTop: $container.data("origHeight")
            });

        // don't do any animation if list shorter than max
        if (multiplier > 1) {
            $container
                .css({
                    height: maxHeight,
                    overflow: "hidden"
                })
                .mousemove(function(e) {
                    var offset = $container.offset();
                    var relativeY = ((e.pageY - offset.top) * multiplier) - ($container.data("origHeight") * multiplier);
                    if (relativeY > $container.data("origHeight")) {
                        $list.css("top", -relativeY + $container.data("origHeight"));
                    };
                });
        }

    }, function() {

        var $el = $(this);

        // put things back to normal
        $el
            .height($(this).data("origHeight"))
            .find("ul")
            .css({ top: 0 })
            .hide()
            .end()
            .find("a")
            .removeClass("hover");

    });
```

Not Working Code

```
  $(document).on("mouseenter", ".dropdown > li", function(){

         var $container = $(this),
             $list = $container.find("ul"),
             $anchor = $container.find("a"),
             height = $list.height() * 1.1,       // make sure there is enough room at the bottom
             multiplier = height / maxHeight;     // needs to move faster if list is taller
        alert("Got here");
        // need to save height here so it can revert on mouseout            
        $container.data("origHeight", $container.height());

        // so it can retain it's rollover color all the while the dropdown is open
        $anchor.addClass("hover");

        // make sure dropdown appears directly below parent list item    
        $list
            .show()
            .css({
                paddingTop: $container.data("origHeight")
            });

        // don't do any animation if list shorter than max
        if (multiplier > 1) {
            $container
                .css({
                    height: maxHeight,
                    overflow: "hidden"
                })
                .mousemove(function(e) {
                    var offset = $container.offset();
                    var relativeY = ((e.pageY - offset.top) * multiplier) - ($container.data("origHeight") * multiplier);
                    if (relativeY > $container.data("origHeight")) {
                        $list.css("top", -relativeY + $container.data("origHeight"));
                    };
                });
        }

    }, function() {

        var $el = $(this);

        // put things back to normal
        $el
            .height($(this).data("origHeight"))
            .find("ul")
            .css({ top: 0 })
            .hide()
            .end()
            .find("a")
            .removeClass("hover");

    });
```

Comment: Its too long code mate, can we inspect this on fiddle ?

Comment: Could you please exactly point out the code section that causing issue, as its tooooo many lines of code to analyse

Comment: It's the first line of each piece of code that I believe is not working. I want a dynamically added piece of content to have the same functionality as the first set of code

Comment: I think the mouse enter is working but mouseleave is not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use delegated event handler for `hover()` you need to use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`

```
$(document).on("mouseenter", ".dropdown > li", function () {

    var $container = $(this),
        $list = $container.find("ul"),
        $anchor = $container.find("a"),
        height = $list.height() * 1.1, // make sure there is enough room at the bottom
        multiplier = height / maxHeight; // needs to move faster if list is taller
    alert("Got here");
    // need to save height here so it can revert on mouseout            
    $container.data("origHeight", $container.height());

    // so it can retain it's rollover color all the while the dropdown is open
    $anchor.addClass("hover");

    // make sure dropdown appears directly below parent list item    
    $list.show()
        .css({
        paddingTop: $container.data("origHeight")
    });

    // don't do any animation if list shorter than max
    if (multiplier > 1) {
        $container.css({
            height: maxHeight,
            overflow: "hidden"
        })
            .mousemove(function (e) {
            var offset = $container.offset();
            var relativeY = ((e.pageY - offset.top) * multiplier) - ($container.data("origHeight") * multiplier);
            if (relativeY > $container.data("origHeight")) {
                $list.css("top", -relativeY + $container.data("origHeight"));
            };
        });
    }

});
$(document).on("mouseleave", ".dropdown > li", function () {
    var $el = $(this);

    // put things back to normal
    $el.height($(this).data("origHeight"))
        .find("ul")
        .css({
        top: 0
    })
        .hide()
        .end()
        .find("a")
        .removeClass("hover");

});
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! I didn't even think about that. It's getting late here